# Excel is open automatically upon windows start

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have an strange problem.

This is Microsoft Office 365 under Windows 10 and I don't remember when, but every time I start the computer, Excel is opened with a blank workbook.

I looked at startup tab in task manager and it is not there.. I also saw in Settings -> Applications -> Startup and it is not there two.

Do you have an advice to avoid this?

Thanks
Jaime

---

Well I did just as you said to do unfortunately though now I **can't get past the windows log in screen because it disabled my fingerprint reader and my pin code**.

*Can you tell me how to set it back to a normal boot up so that I can log back into my computer please.*

Comment: I like a tool called Startup Control Panel. It's no longer maintained, but it can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20131106030702/http://www.mlin.net:80/StartupCPL.shtml 
It provides a single interface where you can see a whole bunch of ways programs might get automatically started. It might not give you all of the possibilities in a Windows 10 environment, but it is a place to start.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that this may be caused by a so-called feature of Microsoft.

Short answer:
Windows Settings->Accounts->Sign-In Options->Privacy->Off

Longer answer:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-word-and-excel-2016-automatically-opens/8d5869df-0212-4f04-9fac-c7e99256a005

Comment: Just had the issue. This fixed it, though note there are two options under "Privacy" now; the one to turn off is "Use my sign-in info ... to reopen my apps after update or restart".

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be from a startup application or service which is opening excel at startup.

Run msconfig from the run dialog(Windows Key + R) to open the System Configuration. From the General Tab choose Selective StartUp, uncheck Load startup items(this will disable all startup items seen in the Task Manager). Apply and reboot your computer. See if it still pops up. If it does, then try also disabling the services by unchecking Load system services in the Selective startup section.

If it doesn't pop up, then you can set your computer back to Normal Startup in the system configuration, and then one by one disabling the Startup apps from the Task Manager to find out which app is causing the issue.